# find average of all numbers in a tableview

Tags: ios, core-data, tableview, swift4, mean

My code below lists the numbers on a tableview. All I want to do is print the average of the numbers in the view did load function. The tableview is getting its numbers from a core data model.

```
        var scores = UITableView()
    var itemName : [NSManagedObject] = []
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return itemName.count


}


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let title = itemName[indexPath.row]
        let cell = scores.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = title.value(forKey: "ee") as? String
        cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center


        cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero

        return cell
    }





   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    var  i = 0;
    var sum = 0;

    for i in 0...itemName.count
    {
        let title = itemName[i]
        let str : String = title.value(forKey: "ee") as! String
        sum = sum + Int(str)!
    }
    var avg = sum/itemName.count

    print("Score Is", avg)
    }
```

[image]

Comment: so actually what is your issue?

Comment: I dont know how to find the average. I dont know where to begin.

Comment: The average of what? Which variable are you trying to average and how is it stored?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop to sum the values in the view did load method

```
    var  i = 0;
    var sum = 0;

    for i in 0...itemName.count-1
    {
        let title = itemName[i]
        let str :String = title.value(forKey: "ee")
        sum = sum + Int(str)
    }

    var avg = sum/itemName.count
```

Comment: I am getting a error message on sum = sum + title.value(forKey: "ee"), Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'Any?'

Comment: Can you try type casting the title.value(forKey: "ee") to Int. Or make the sum same as the value for the key "ee". What type of value is stored in title for key "ee"?

Comment: ee is stored as a string/

Comment: Can you share a sample string

Comment: I added a picture hope that helps dont know what you mean by sample string.

Comment: your updated answer gives error Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Int' with an argument list of type '(Any?)'

Comment: I edited my question above with code that builds however it causes a runtime error. At let title line stating "Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188564/discussion-between-pooja-and-silly-milly).